# column AS alias throws 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException'

Tags: c#, wpf, oracle, exception, datagrid

In my WPF application, using Oracle database and C#, I have this code to fill a datagrid, but it throws 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException', and 'Table 0 cannot be found'.

If I remove `AS Date` from the SQL, no exception is thrown, but the datagrid displays the column name as `to_char(date_, 'dd/mm/yyyy')` in the application

```
        db.SetSql("select sn, activity, attendees, to_char(date_, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AS Date from cpr");

        DataSet result = db.RetrieveRecords();

        datagrid1.ItemsSource = new DataView(result.Tables[0]);
```

Comment: Try to enclose "Date" in "As Date" in double quotes

Comment: @VasylMoskalov , still throws the same exception, and only enclosed in single quotes because it's already in a string

Comment: What is the implementation of RetrieveRecords?

Comment: I think your query is not correct...did you try run query directly in SQL to see if it works....Query is wrong...it is ending up with exception...RetrieveRecord method swallows the exception and returns empty dataset....you are trying to access item in empty dataset which is causing the exception

Comment: @Viru, the query `select sn, activity, attendees, to_char(date_, 'dd/mm/yyyy) from cpr` works in sqlplus, but not with `AS Date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to correct your query. date is data type in oracle so that is why the alias is not working.

Either enclose it in double quotes or change the column name it self.

Try this query in SQL plus..it should work

```
select sn, activity, attendees, to_char(date_, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AS "Date" from cpr
```

then try this in C#

```
db.SetSql("select sn, activity, attendees, to_char(date_, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AS \"Date\" from cpr");
```

Answer (score 1):

Could be because `Date` is a [key word](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a42525/apb.htm) in `Oracle`. Try changing your query like below by escaping the keyword

```
    db.SetSql("select sn, activity, attendees, to_char(date_, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AS \"Date\" from cpr");
```